# Comparing UIColor name

Tags: objective-c, uicolor

I need to compare a color name. I have this code but it doesn't work =(

What should I do?

```
-(IBAction)buttonSelect:(id)sender {
  if ([sender color] == [UIColor redColor]) {
    // do something.
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also, read up on pointers and pointer comparisons. If you previously programmed in Java or C#, for instance, `==` does not do what you think it does in Objective-C.

Comment: Do you want to compare the `UIColor` objects or the name of the colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ([[sender titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIColor redColor]]) 
{
   // do something
}
```

This is how you compare objects in objective-c, as objects are pointers and you can't compare pointers with `==`. I'd advise you to look into this

Comment: Sorry dont work i have this error  ---  '-[UIButton color]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a68800'--

Comment: The error is saying `sender` is a `UIButton`.

Comment: Are you trying to compare the `backgroundColor` of the button? If so, then it would be `[sender backgroundColor]`.

Comment: @Fabio ok thats the code you provided. What color are you trying to check?

Comment: Sorry i have an error this works!!!

Comment: if ([[sender titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIColor redColor]])

Comment: @Fabio ok ill update the code for anyone else

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
if ([[sender titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIColor redColor]])
```